# How do you solve N+1 for ActiveStorage URLs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

How do you preload all the records with their URLs?

This is what I am doing in my jbuilder to get the URLs:

```
# views/users/index.json.jbuilder
...
json.avatar_url user.avatar.attached? && rails_blob_url(user.avatar)
...


Comment
    has_one :user

User
    has_one_attached :avatar
```

How would you preload all the users and their avatars?

---

```
Comments.includes(users: :avatar)
```

yields the following error:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError (Association named 'avatar' was not found on User; perhaps you misspelled it?)

The same error pops up when executing:

```
User.includes(:avatar)
```

Comment: You do this for a list of users ? Can you also attach location where you populate this list of users ?

Comment: @Nermin Added. I think that's what you were asking for.

Comment: What is `user.avatar` and how does it relate to `User`? From your error it seems like it's not an association. Is it an attribute?

Comment: @JohanWentholt I just added an update.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For a singular attachment named `:avatar`, Active Storage adds a `with_attached_avatar` scope that preloads the relevant associations:

```
@users.with_attached_avatar.each do |user|
  # ...
end
```

See the API documentation for [`has_one_attached`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Model.html#method-i-has_one_attached).

Comment: What if I am pulling all comments and trying to preload users and their avatars?

Comment: Ah I found it! ```includes(users: :avatar_attachment)```. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Strawberry, close. You’ll want to use `includes(users: { avatar_attachment: :blob })` to preload the blobs as well.

Comment: Actually :avatar_attachment worked for me and reduced my response time significantly.

Comment: What to do when Multiple Attachments are Present, I really like the `with_attached_variablename` command

Comment: @FaizaanKhan, an equivalent scope is added for plural attachments: for example, `@users.with_attached_highlights`.

Comment: Rails 6 doc @ https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Model.html#method-i-has_one_attached