# Ruby on Rails Active Storage (bug?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activestorage

I've encountered something really strange, like I see I may be the first one tackling with this. To the basis - I've got a table with all employees, each employee has an NFC id card as id column, their name and now I wanted them to have a "profile picture", something like this.
I decided to use Active Storage library, everything works fine with query N + 1, fetching all employees and for each of them fetch separately their profile picture. I don't want to drain my database so I decided to optimise it and here comes the bug I would say.

**Here is the N + 1 query:**

```
@employees = Employee.all.map do |employee|
  { :id => employee.id, :name => employee.name, :avatar => employee.avatar.attached? ? url_for(employee.avatar) : nil }
end
```

**The result of the first fetched employee:**

```
{
  "id": "0029216630",
  "name": "SPECIAL WORKS9",
  "avatar": "http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--45c6a565c85aede1125f25bacd31d70297362a73/IMG_4629.JPG"
}
```

And this is how it is supposed to work, now let's go ahead to the "optimised" query, yes, with quotation marks 'cause I don't even know whether I'm doing it correctly.

**Optimised query**

```
@employees = Employee.with_attached_avatar.all.map do |employee|
  { :id => employee.id, :name => employee.name, :avatar => employee.avatar.attached? ? url_for(employee.avatar) : nil }
end
```

**The result of optimised query**

```
{
  "id": "0029216630",
  "name": "SPECIAL WORKS9",
  "avatar": null
}
```

Nevertheless, there is attached an image to the record, rails cannot see this image, like there is no any.

**The Employee model definition**

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :started_occurrences, foreign_key: :start_employee, class_name: "Occurrence"
  has_many :finished_occurrences, foreign_key: :finish_employee, class_name: "Occurrence"
  has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

**It's an API Rails app**
Got frontend built upon React.

Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you solve N+1 for ActiveStorage URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785703/how-do-you-solve-n1-for-activestorage-urls)

Comment: Nope, Employee.includes(avatar_attachment: :blob).find("0029216630") - doesn't work, fetches correctly blob, attachment is nil.

Comment: no insight into your question... but the id field doesn't look right... in ActiveRecord, the idiomatic Rails implementation has the id field as a bigint starting at 1 and incrementing automatically. Your implementation is unusual, I urge you to adhere to the Rails norms... it will make your life much easier! I doubt is is causing the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Actually it was causing the problem you were seeing. The employee id was a string as a sequence of digits. Active Storage set this field as a indeed bigint and string was coerced to bigint. I've changed it to string in the migration, and everything works fine since then.